# Android : Two Spinner in the same layout

Tags: android

I'm currently experiencing a problem :

I put two Spinner in a same RelativeLayout but when I'm clicking the second Spinner in my android app, the logcat tells me a warning (cf example.png).

Could you explain me this warning and help me to solve it please ?
Thanks in advance,

Here is the activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the logcat warning :

```
10-27 23:06:02.284: W/InputEventReceiver(30096): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: Just showing the layout XML isn't enough. You need to show the code that's handling the events.

Comment: You need to show the code that's handling the events.